# Copy a file from a computer to a SharePoint folder either using xcopy or robocopy

Tags: windows, sharepoint

I am trying to copy a file that is stored on a local disk C on my computer to a SharePoint folder using either xcopy or robocopy. is there any way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why was it unsuccessful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the
[net use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11))
command to map a SharePoint library to a drive letter and then use
`copy` or `xcopy` or `robocopy` and others.

The command will look similar to :

```
net use r: https://some.portal.org/documents [password] user:domainName\[username]
copy c:\somefile.txt r:\somefile.txt
```